# Differences in time from spreadsheet in PHP

Tags: php

I am new here. Please dont judge me.

This is my script which is CSV spreadsheet with people which race with start time and end time.
i want to get the differences in the minutes . I get Output : 10:45 - 11:45 = 21 , i know i have to convert that to a time, but i don't know how. Im newbie .

Thank you in advance :)

```
<?php
const  Start = 2;
const  Finish  = 3;

$startTime = 0;
$endTime  = 0;


$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("racing.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
      $startTime = $data[Start];
      $endTime =  $data[Finish];
    }
    fclose($handle);
     echo "Difference ".$startTime."+".$endTime." = ".($startTime + $endTime);
}
?>
```

Comment: Convert the values into minutes first (explode at `:`, first part * 60 + second part), get the difference, and then convert back into `hh:mm` format. (At least the latter should be easy enough to research yourself, if you have no idea how to.)

Comment: Thank you for the advice CBroe :) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $startTime = $data[Start];
  $endTime =  $data[Finish];
  $startParts = explode(":", $startTime);
  $endParts = explode(":", $endTime);
  $startMinute = (int)$startParts[1];
  $startHour = (int)$startParts[0];
  $endMinute = (int)$endParts[1];
  $endHour = (int)$endParts[0];
  $differenceHour = ($endHour - $startHour);
  $differenceMinute = ($endMinute - $startMinute);
  $differenceHour -= (($differenceMinute < 0) ? 1 : 0);
  if ($differenceMinute < 0) $differenceMinute += 60;
  $difference = $differenceHour * 60 + $differenceMinute;
```

Explanation:

- we get `$startTime` and `$endTime` as composite raw texts, such as 09:23
- we divide them using `explode`, the 0th elements will be hours, the 1th elements will be minutes
- we store the parts accordingly into `$startMinute`, `$startHour`, `$endMinute`, `$endHour`
- we compute the difference of hours and store the result into `$differenceHour`
- we compute the difference of minutes and store the result into `$differenceMinute`
- if `$differenceMinute` is negative, that means that in terms of minute start time has a higher value, we need to subtract this from the hours result
- if `$differenceMinute` was negative, then we need to compute the invert subtraction, that is, if we had 21 - 37, then we will end up with 42, so, 21 - 37 = -18 and if we add 60, we end up with 42
- finally we compute the result of the results and store it into `$difference`, which is the result that you need

Comment: That is perfect ! This worked very well :) Thank you !